# AutoCompleteSource for textbox in Compact Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, autocomplete, textbox, compact-framework, .net-cf-3.5

Does anyone know how to do `AutoCompleteSource` for TextBox UI element in Compact Framework 3.5? (with C#) To display suggestions, as user types into TextBox, from data in specified dataset?

Here is link from Microsoft that describes how to use `AutoCompleteSource`, but I can't find it with compact framework 3.5. Are there any alternative to this?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode(v=vs.90).aspx

The data that I want to use for suggestions is already imported into dataset in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those tools are not built into the CF Developer Controls like they are with Windows Forms and Web controls.

You could manually make something, I suppose, by making a ListBox visible below your TextBox.

It isn't that it can't be done, you just have to create it yourself if you really want it.

Comment: THanks. I ended up making something myself.